# npm fast-lorem-ipsum not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

```
`var fastLoremIpsum = require('fast-lorem-ipsum').fastLoremIpsum;
console.log(fastLoremIpsum(10,'c'));`
```

I was trying to use fast-lorem-ipsum npm package but on executing above code in nodejs file,instead of getting lorem-ipsum text i am getting 'undefined' as console output.
What should i do ?

Comment: Did you even read the docs? You need `var fastLoremIpsum = require('fast-lorem-ipsum').fastLoremIpsum;`.

Comment: But still it is showing 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-lorem-ipsum) for the package, the function you're looking for should be accessed like this —

```
var fastLoremIpsum = require('fast-lorem-ipsum').fastLoremIpsum;
console.log(fastLoremIpsum(10,'c'));
```